# Angular JS - Dynamically Choose Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building an app that allows the user to select different widgets through a GUI.   The goal is to implement the various widgets as angular directives.

```
THE CONTROLLER
$scope.widgets = ['one', 'two', 'three'];


THE TEMPLATE
<{{widget}} ng-repeat="widget in widgets"></{{widget}}>
```

Does anyone know the best way to make this work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to take a look in [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

I'm creating dynamic content in this way:

```
$compile('<one ng-repeat="widget in widgets"></one>')($scope);
```

I took the idea from this post: [angularjs dynamic templates](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/)

I hope that this helps.